# Linkedin v2 me API does not return position value

Tags: php, linkedin-api

When I used the following API, it returns only firstname, lastname and id datas:
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me

It does not return data such as position and headline.

When I look at the documentation, it should return all the data.
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/people/profile-api

When I try the following api, it is doing the same thing, it returns only the first name, lastname and id :

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName,maidenName,phoneticFirstName,phoneticLastName,headline,location,industryName,summary,specialties,positions,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams),vanityName,lastModified,organizations)

Comment: I expect the returned data will relate to the permission you requested from the user. Perhaps you haven't requested enough? See the `scope` parameter in the oauth request https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2

Comment: Hey when I am trying to integrate to v2, I am getting Not enough permissions to access: GET /me with error code 403. Please can you guide me how to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me will return  : firstName,lastName,profilePicture,id

r_emailaddress will return : emailAddress

for position and headline or for calling : https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/people/profile-api - you have to apply for r_basicprofile to Linkedin because there information not available in V2 r_liteprofile

Check this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq?context=linkedin/consumer/context